# How to use href that links to already opened page

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Cpanel File Manager]

If you click Cpanel File Manager hyperlink, it opens the file manager page in new tab. If you click again, it reloads the already opened tab, rather opening in a new tab again. How to achieve this in our web page.

Comment: `<a href="link2.html"  target="_blank somename"> Hello link </a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`target` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) to a name, and the browser will reuse that window if it already exists.

Comment: `<a href="link2.html"  target="_blank somename"> Hello link </a>` Worked. Thanks